# TypeError: object function can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, web3.py

Пишу бота на асинхронном web3.
Вот пример функции:

```
async def multicall_check_amounts(w3, multicall_address, contract_address, token_address_list, WBNB_PRICE, result1):
        multicall_contract = w3.eth.contract(address=multicall_address, abi=[TRY_AGGREGATE_ABI])
        encoded_calls = []
        names = []
        for i in token_address_list:
            encoded_calls.append(i['buy_data'])
            encoded_calls.append(i['sell_data'])
            names.append({'name':i['name'],'decimals0':i['decimals0']})

        calls = [
            {"target": contract_address,'allowFailure': True, "callData": call_data}
            for call_data in encoded_calls
        ]
        data = await multicall_contract.functions.tryAggregate(False, calls).call()
        print(data)
```

ошибка в строке data = await multicall_contract.functions.tryAggregate(False, calls).call()
в чем может быть дело? передаю асинхронный web3 в функцию

Comment: А что в итоге возвращает `call()`?

Comment: TypeError: object function can't be used in 'await' expression